# Android move file to External Device with press of Button

Tags: android, external

I need to make a button so that it moves a specific file to the External Drive. I have set the manifest so it allows to write to External Storage but I can not find the code to write a specific file to write to the External Storage.

Comment: Use `getExternalFilesDir()` or related methods on `Context`, or `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` on `Environment`, to get a `File` object pointing to a root location on external storage. From there, it is just standard Java file I/O (create a `File` object based on that root to the specific location, open a `FileInputStream` and a `FileOutputStream`, copy the bytes, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following permissions if writing/reading external memory in your **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

called like this:

```
copyExt("/storage/emulated/0/obb/Orange.txt","");

//turn String path names into File descriptors
public void copyExt (String pathInternal, String pathExternal) {
    File fInternal = new File (pathInternal);//pathInternal must exist
//    File fExternal = new File (pathExternal);//pathExternal must exist
    String filename=path.substring(pathInternal.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    File fExternal = new File(Environment.getExternalStorage().getAbsolutePath()+"/filename");

    copyFile(fInternal,fExternal);
}

//make it static so we can re-use it, in a Utils class
    public static void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
            FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();
            inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (inChannel != null)
                inChannel.close();
            if (outChannel != null)
                outChannel.close();
        }
    }
```

**ALTERNATIVE**

```
public static boolean copyFile(String from, String to) {
try {
    int bytesum = 0;
    int byteread = 0;
    File oldfile = new File(from);
    if (oldfile.exists()) {
        InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(from);
        FileOutputStream fs  = new FileOutputStream(to);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1444];
        while ((byteread = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            bytesum += byteread;
            fs.write(buffer, 0, byteread);
        }
        inStream.close();
        fs.close();
    }
    return true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: So if the file name is Orange.txt, it would need to say...

copyExt ("/storage/emulated/0/obb/"Orange.txt" optional/external-USB/obb");

Comment: If the file is at  "/storage/emulated/0/obb/Orange.txt" (I fill in the second argument for you so pass an empty string) then copyExt ("/storage/emulated/0/obb/Orange.txt" , "");